# Button action does not react when .touchUpInside inside a navigation bar

Tags: swift, xcode, navigationbar

I created a UICollectionViewController to simulate a Feed app and I wanted to configure the top navigation bar similar to the Twitter one, with custom buttons that trigger actions, here's mine

[image]

The problem I'm facing is that when I click on the black profile icon, the action is not triggered.

Here's my code:

```js
import UIKit

class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController {

  //MARK: - Properties

  private lazy var profileButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "person.fill"), for: .normal)
        button.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x79CBBF)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapProfile), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
     // MARK: - Lifecycle
    
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupNavBar()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Helpers
    
  func setupNavBar() {
        let width = view.frame.width
        let titleView = UIView()
        titleView.backgroundColor = .clear
        titleView.frame = .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 50)
        
        titleView.addSubview(profileButton)
        
        profileButton.tintColor = .black
        profileButton.centerY(inView: titleView, leftAnchor: titleView.leftAnchor, paddingLeft: 0)
        
        
        titleView.addSubview(filterButton)
        filterButton.centerY(inView: titleView, leftAnchor: profileButton.rightAnchor,          paddingLeft: view.frame.width - 60 - 16)
        navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    }
    
   // MARK: - Actions
   @objc func didTapProfile() {
       print("did tap profile")
    }
```

As said below, I added a .addTarget to the button but the #selector(didTapProfile) function does not get triggered when the button is inside the navigation bar.

Any hints on how to do this?

Comment: I feel like you are doing this wrong using the `titleView` and stuff. UINavigationBar has all sorts of conveniences for doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a title view and measuring its size and stuff... there are a load of convenience functions for doing this...

Take a look here... https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-add-a-bar-button-to-a-navigation-bar

You can do something like...

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(didTapProfile))
```

There are different ways to create `UIBarButtonItem` with images and text also...

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem